# how to create a template with express-handlebars?

Tags: express, templates, handlebars.js

There is a problem with my `exphbs` function and it says that it doesn't exist.

I already tried `npm install express-handlebars@latest`, `npm install express-handlebars`, `npm install --save express-handlebars` but none has worked.
I already have this code:

// app.js

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

// Configurar o mecanismo de template Handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Renderizar a view 'index' e passar dados para o template
  res.render('index', { message: 'Hello, World!' });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your install of express-handlebars, but rather due to a misunderstanding of what the module *exports*.

The [express-handlebars documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) has in its first code example the following lines:

```
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
```

This is telling us that the default export of the express-handlebars module includes an `engine` function and that function is to be invoked and the result passed to the `app.engine` call as the second argument.

Your code includes the following:

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
```

In this code, you are importing the default export of `express-handlebars` and assigning it to `exphbs`. Based on what is said above, we know that `exphbs` is an object with a member function `engine`. But your code tries to invoke `exphbs` instead of invoking `exphbs.engine`. As `exphbs` is *not* a function, the `exphbs()` call results in a "TypeError: exphbs is not a function" error.

We need to fix the mismatch between the import and the invocation. Either of the following will suffice:

```
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

const app = express();

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs.engine());
```

Alternatively, destructuring the default export:

```
const { engine } = require("express-handlebars");

const app = express();

app.engine("handlebars", engine());
```